# Neo4j: Variable-length-relationship with intermediary node

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j database with two types of node labels: person and email.
One email node always connects two person nodes through the relationships 'EMAIL_FROM' and 'EMAIL_TO'
such that the relationship can be queried like such:

```
match (p1:Person)-[:EMAIL_FROM]->(:Email)-[:EMAIL_TO]->(p2:Person) return p1, p2
```

I'm trying to write a variable-length-relationship query which begins at a certain person node and finds all other person nodes that can be reached through the intermediary email nodes. This is what I tried:

```
match (p1:Person where p1.name='Jeff')-[:EMAIL_FROM*]->(:Email)-[:EMAIL_TO*]->(p2:Person) return p1, p2
```

This sadly does not work as I thought it would and returns only directly reachable from the 'Jeff' node by iterating through the pattern once but then it stops although I know the nodes reached in the first iteration have outgoing 'EMAIL_FROM' relationships themselves. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you want to continuous follow a flow of sent emails to all reachable persons (all persons who Jeff sent emails to, and from all of them all the persons they sent emails to, repeating forever)? Keep in mind for any non-trivial graph this may not terminate quickly, and you may blow your heap memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to continuously follow a pattern of sent emails, you could use quantified path patterns to do so:

```
MATCH (p1:Person where p1.name='Jeff') (()-[:EMAIL_FROM]->(:Email)-[:EMAIL_TO]->(:Person))+ (p2)
RETURN DISTINCT p2
```

This will repeat the last part of the pattern with a lower bound of 1 and no upper bound. For any non-trivial graph this may not finish, and you may have heap issues. We would recommend setting an upper bound if possible.

Another approach would be to use APOC Procedures, the path explorer procedures, as those might be more efficient in finding distinct reachable nodes.

```
MATCH (p1:Person where p1.name='Jeff') 
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(p1, {relationshipFilter:'EMAIL_FROM>, EMAIL_TO>', labelFilter:'>Person'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

This will repeat outgoing :EMAIL_FROM and :EMAIL_TO relationships, returning only :Person nodes, and the uniqueness used by this procedure should only return distinct end nodes.

Comment: I tested the first approach on a slimmed down custom database and it works, thank you. Sadly, my other database is running Neo4J Server 5.7 which does not yet support quantified path patterns.